# How to remove substrings marked with special characters from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in Python:

```
Tt = "This is a <\"string\">string, It should be <\"changed\">changed to <\"a\">a nummber."

print Tt

'This is a <"string">string, It should be <"changed">changed to <"a">a nummber.'
```

You see the some words repeat in this part `<\"  \">.`

My question is, how to delete those repeated parts (delimited with the named characters)?

The result should be like:

```
'This is a string, It should be changed to a nummber.'
```

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: Sharing with us the methods that you have already tried is a great way to express the difficulties you are facing. We can address specific areas of your attempts that are problematic.

Comment: Come on! You can come up with a better title.

Comment: @JulienBernu I used the for loop. Sorry as a beginner. But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
Tt = re.sub('<\".*?\">', '', Tt)
```

Note the `?` after `*`. It makes the expression non-greedy,
so it tries to match so few symbols between `<\"` and `\">` as possible.

The Solution of *James* will work only in cases when the delimiting substrings
consist only from one character (`<` and `>`). In this case it is possible to use negations like `[^>]`. If you want to remove a substring delimited with character sequences (e.g. with `begin` and `end`), you should use non-greedy regular expressions (i.e. `.*?`).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a quick regular expression:

```
import re
Tt = "This is a <\"string\">string, It should be <\"changed\">changed to <\"a\">a number."
print re.sub("<[^<]+>","",Tt)
#Out: This is a string, It should be changed to a nummber.
```

Ah - similar to Igor's post, he beat my by a bit. Rather than making the expression non-greedy, I don't match an expression if it contains another start tag "<" in it, so it will only match a start tag that's followed by an end tag ">".

Comment: @James: I've written a small update to my answer, regarding that why or when it's better to use non-greedy regular expressions.